# InputConnectionWrapper getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection LOGCAT Warning

Tags: java, android, warnings, logcat

I get an InputConnectionWrapper warning everytime I turn toutch over the edittext. I don't know why, because I don't use InputConnection.

**getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection**

**Here is the LogCat Output image.**
[image]

```
edtValue.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    String value1= edtCantidad.getText().toString();
    String value2= edtResto.getText().toString();
    String value3= edtBonif.getText().toString();
    calcValues(); // this method clear values so, I need to put them back                                   
    edtResto.setText(value1);
    edtCantidad.setText(value2);
    edtBonif.setText(value3);

    return false;
    }
});
```